# Batch file cannot find .exe despite the path being correct

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a .bat file to launch two programs, not having success so far. I've followed the guide [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/launch-multiple-programs-single-shortcut-using-batch-file/).

```
@echo off
cd "D:\CRCR 0.4.0\"
start "" "D:\CRCR 0.4.0\Chernobyl Relay Chat Rebirth.exe"
cd "D:\MO2\" 
start "" "D:\MO2\ModOrganizer.exe moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher"
exit
```

Whenever I try to launch the batch file, it tells me "Windows cannot find 'D:\MO2\ModOrganizer.exe "moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again."

I've tried removing 'start' from those lines, removing quotations from the cd lines, etc. How can I get this working?

Comment: **2.** ```cd "D:\CRCR 0.4.0\"``` should read as ```CD /D "D:\CRCR 0.4.0" 2>NUL || Exit /B``` and **3.** ```start "" "D:\CRCR 0.4.0\Chernobyl Relay Chat Rebirth.exe"``` should read as ```Start "" "Chernobyl Relay Chat Rebirth.exe"```. **5.** should read as ```Start "" "ModOrganizer.exe" "moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher"```. Otherwise you should use the `/D` option with your start commands: ```Start "" /D "D:\CRCR 0.4.0" "Chernobyl Relay Chat Rebirth.exe"``` and ```Start "" /D "D:\MO2" "ModOrganizer.exe" "moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher"```

Comment: In addition to Compo's suggestion to code the batch file correct, remove `exit` from the batch file. A command line with just `exit` at end of the batch file is useless and just counterproductive. I recommend to read the usage help of commands which are not working as expected by opening a command prompt window and running the command with `/?` as argument. Try it out with `cd /?` and `start /?` and you should get the knowledge why your command lines fail and the command lines suggested by Compo work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to pass `moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher` as a parameter.

In that case you should also separate the string:

```
start "" "D:\MO2\ModOrganizer.exe" "moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher"
```

Otherwise Windows will interpret the path as `D:\MO2\ModOrganizer.exe moshortcut://:Anomaly Launcher` not `D:\MO2\ModOrganizer.exe` and assume that the entire string is part of the path.